# where is this zeros came from inside the c main function stack memory area in gdb?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, stack

I have below source c souce code

```
professor@Linux:~/$ cat stack2.c 
#include<stdio.h>

int function(int a , int b) 
{
        int x = 10;
        int y = 20;
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i = 5;
        int j = 15;
        function(100,7);
        int k = 30;
        return 0;

}
```

I have compiled above c source code by using below options on my linux

```
professor@Linux:~/$ gcc -z execstack stack2.c -o stack2


with my ubuntu version:

professor@Linux:~/$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 7.04
Release:        7.04
Codename:       feisty
```

then I have disassembled the main inside the gdb and put a breakpoint then i have analysed the stack area of main function as below

```
professor@Linux:~ $ gdb -q ./stack2

Using host libthread_db library "/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libthread_db.so.1".
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0804835f <main+0>:    push   ebp
0x08048360 <main+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x08048362 <main+3>:    sub    esp,0x18
0x08048365 <main+6>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x08048368 <main+9>:    mov    eax,0x0
0x0804836d <main+14>:   sub    esp,eax
0x0804836f <main+16>:   mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-4],0x5
0x08048376 <main+23>:   mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-8],0xf
0x0804837d <main+30>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+4],0x7
0x08048385 <main+38>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x64
0x0804838c <main+45>:   call   0x8048344 <function>
0x08048391 <main+50>:   mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-12],0x1e
0x08048398 <main+57>:   mov    eax,0x0
0x0804839d <main+62>:   leave  
0x0804839e <main+63>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b * 0x0804836f
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804836f
(gdb) display/8wx $esp
(gdb) display/2i $eip
(gdb) run AAAAA
Starting program: /home/professor/stack2 AAAAA

Breakpoint 1, 0x0804836f in main ()
2: x/2i $eip
0x804836f <main+16>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-4],0x5
0x8048376 <main+23>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-8],0xf
1: x/8xw $esp
0xbffffc30:     0xb7ff47b0      0x080483b0      0x00000000      0xb7fd6ff4
0xbffffc40:     0xb8000ce0      0x080483b0      0xbffffca8      0xb7eafebc
(gdb)
```

So my question is what is this "0x00000000" between 0x080483b0 and 0xb7fd6ff4 onto the stack area of main, everything is understood but i am not able to identify this "0x00000000".
So can anyone have any idea what is this 0x00000000 inside the main stack memory area?

Comment: Idon't really understand the question (I don't see any range of 0 in what you shown) but anyway, the stack is setup by the kernel at program start, and pages allocated for the stack are filled with 0 (by the kernel). So very likely the 0 you get are just here as "default values".

Comment: focus on the second last line of gdb output between the values 0x080483b0,0xb7fd6ff4 there are 0x00000000. where these zeroes came from thats my question. When i use only main function there are no zeroes onto the stack area of main.

Comment: If you can do `watch -l *(int *)0xbffffc38` - I'm not sure if that'll work in an old GDB or in a VM - that will let you see which pre-main functions are writing to that location on the stack.